# How to login to this website with Python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to login to a website with requests library in Python. I tried different codes with no luck. This is my code:

```
url = 'https://www.damejidlo.cz/en/profile/prihlaseni'
login_data = {'email': 'test',
              'password': 'password',
              'do': 'loginForm-submit'}
session = requests.session()
session.headers.update({'do': 'loginForm-submit'})
result = session.post(url, data=login_data)
if "test@lolco.net" in result.content:
    print("example.com:", "logged in")
elif "Sign up" in result.content:
    print("example.com:", "not logged in")
```

How to make it work? You can use user data to test login. I will delete that account afterwards. Thanks!

If I run this code, I get `example.com: not logged in`. I wanna be logged in :D

Comment: What do you mean *"no luck"*?

Comment: I got response 200 code, but I was not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple, you just need to add a user-agent:

```
In [7]: import requests

In [8]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [9]: login = "https://www.damejidlo.cz/en/profile/prihlaseni"

In [10]: data = {"email": "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
   ....:         "password": "xxxxxxxx",
   ....:         "do": "loginForm-submit"}

In [11]: h = {
   ....:     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36"}

In [12]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ....:         r = s.post(login, data=data, headers=h)
   ....:         soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
   ....:         print(soup.select_one("#snippet--user-bar a.username.user-bar__links-item").text)
   ....:     

xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. That actually crossed my mind, but for some reason I added it to data, not headers param :(

Comment: No worries, the only thing that should be in data is what you are posting, the user-agent etc.. are all part of the request headers